# Redis gem 4.6.0: Multi pipeline commands warnings in sidekiq logs

Tags: redis, sidekiq

I'm using sidekiq to run background jobs in ROR application. Recently redis gem version got updated to 4.6.0 (automatically as sidekiq dependency), but its producing some multi pipeline commands warning continuously as sidekiq logs flooded with these logs and its difficult to track Worker logs. Please let me know how can i remove these warnings?

Sidekiq logs:

```
(called from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/sidekiq-6.4.0/lib/sidekiq/launcher.rb:141:in `block in ❤'}
Pipelining commands on a Redis instance is deprecated and will be removed in Redis 5.0.0.

redis.multi do
  redis.get("key")
end

should be replaced by

redis.multi do |pipeline|
  pipeline.get("key")
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the reason for that:

> That’s from the Redis gem. 6.4.1 will be released Monday and fix it.
> Downgrade that gem or use Sidekiq’s main branch if you want an immediate
> fix.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/5178#issuecomment-1029545859

Comment: Yes its fixed now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. The response from onerinas is correct. For simplicity, below is the code needed to upgrade the sidekiq gem. This fixed the issue for me.

```
gem 'sidekiq', '>= 6.4.1'
```

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/5169#issuecomment-1029171282

Comment: Yes, in version 6.4.1 it's fixed.